# Pandas in Python: how to exclude results with a count == 1?

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the code I currently have:

```
df.groupby(df['LOCAL_COUNCIL']).agg({'CRIME_RATING': ['mean', 'count']}).reset_index()
```

which returns something like the following (I've made these values up):

```
      CRIME_RATING
              mean   count
0         3.000000       1
1         3.118397      39
2         2.790698      32 
3         5.125000      18
4         4.000000       1
5         4.222222      22
```

but I'd quite like to exclude indexes 0 and 4 from the resulting dataframe given that they both have a `count` of 1. Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) for filter not equal `1` with `tuple` for select `MultiIndex` columns and filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['LOCAL_COUNCIL']).agg({'CRIME_RATING': ['mean', 'count']}).reset_index()
df2 = df1[df1[('CRIME_RATING','count')].ne(1)]
```

If want avoid `MultiIndex` use named aggregation:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df['LOCAL_COUNCIL']).agg(mean = ('CRIME_RATING','mean'),
                                         count = ('CRIME_RATING','count'))

df2 = df1[df1['count'].ne(1)]
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for - thanks. Realised I can also use ```Series.ge``` and ```Series.le``` for greater-than-or-equal-to and less-than-or-equal-to respectively.